# Spacing after environ to only affect horizontal space?

Tags: spacing

I'm trying to create an environ called displayquote (similar to the one provided by csquotes but not quite). When you have a block quote, regardless of whether you want to start a new paragraph after the quote, the vertical spacing will be the same. However, if you want to start a new paragraph, you should add an indent. I've gotten foo to look the way I want it to, but bar adds all of this spacing that I don't want. I understand why this spacing is like it is now, but how do I make it so that bar will have the same spacing after the quote as foo but it will be indented? Essentially, I need some way to look into the future to see if the user puts an empty line after my environ or not. Any help is appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\NewEnviron{displayquote}[0]
{

\vspace*{1em}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-80pt-\parindent}
\BODY
\end{minipage}\vspace*{1em}

\hspace*{-\parindent}}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur malesuada, quam sed vulputate rhoncus, sapien quam venenatis tellus.
\begin{displayquote}
``Nam tincidunt metus sapien, vitae tempus purus sodales at. Nulla facilisi. Nunc non elementum nisi.''
\end{displayquote}
foo

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur malesuada, quam sed vulputate rhoncus, sapien quam venenatis tellus.
\begin{displayquote}
``Nam tincidunt metus sapien, vitae tempus purus sodales at. Nulla facilisi. Nunc non elementum nisi.''
\end{displayquote}

bar
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! I can do

```
\begin{itemize}[label=,\leftmargin=(desired value)]
\item stuff
\end{itemize}
```